# TCP port for android application

Tags: android, tcp

I am writing application for android. It is require tcp connection with my server. Unfortunately, tcp port 8100 was blocked by my provider and i has not got a connection with wifi. With 3G application works fine.

What is the most suitable port for application communication?

Answer (score 0):

Any port that is not reserved, so port range would be [1024-65534]